# Close all browsers with selenium when using multithreads

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, firefox, browser

I m doing web scraping with selenium. And i m using multithreads library. My script opens 3 firefox browsers at the same time and scraping. After finished to scraping, i want to close all browsers, i tried many way but Browser.quit() and browser.close() closing 1 browser, other 2 browser do not close.

```
def get_links():
   some code here...
def get_driver():
   global driver
   driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'driver', None)
   if driver is None:
       chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
       chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
       driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path)
       setattr(threadLocal, 'driver', driver)
return driver

def get_title(thisdict):
   import datetime
   driver = get_driver()
   driver.get(thisdict["url"])
   time.sleep(5)
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ThreadPool(3).map(get_title, get_links())
   driver.close()  #or driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the `self.selenium.stop()` function. The `quit()`basically calls `driver.dispose` method which in turn closes all the browser windows. `close()` closes the browser window on which the focus is set.

Comment: Thanks for answer Aleksander, but ı dont understand how can ı implement this answer to my code, can you explain it more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the code below. After Multithread finished all scraping, I m calling closeBrowsers function. And the function kills all open firefox browsers.

```
import os

def closeBrowsers():
    os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreadPool(2).map(get_title, get_links())
    closeBrowsers()
```